# Is there no "exploration speed" in DCC RPG?

Tags: movement, travel, dungeon-crawl-classics-rpg

DCC RPG distinguishes between ten-second rounds for combat, and ten-minute turns for exploration (p. 76), and gives speeds for actions (p. 77) and for overland moment (p. 308), but appears to be missing "exploration speed" (or movement per turn) which is to be found in most OSR games (e.g. LotFP Rules & Magic, p. 38). Is this the case, or am I missing something?

Is the intention that you just count movement generally action-by-action (ie per 10-second round), but then round up to a ten-minute turn after combat*? This would make dungeon exploration much faster in DCC RPG than in other old school games, and would also seem to make the idea of a ten-minute exploration turn somewhat redundant.

* The latter part of this - that you round up to a full turn after a combat - is explicitly stated on p. 76.

Answer (score 1):

Movement per turn for exploration is not addressed in DCC. Honestly, unless a particular dungeon requires it, timekeeping usually isn’t bothered with outside of combat.

The one instance I recall non-combat timekeeping mattering in an official DCC module was when the PCs were navigating a space that they had previously explored and were now fleeing with all haste. The module directed the Judge to count rounds.

The Judge is empowered to add what they want, of course.

Comment: I'm running Well of the Worm at the moment, which says to check for random encounters every 30 minutes, which is what got me thinking about this question. As action-based movement is so quick, this basically would mean only after every three combats, as as the chance of a random encounter is only 1 in 12 it makes it pretty unlikely that one will ever happen. It's good to have the confirmation that the rules don't cover exploration speed, but I've decided to introduce it using 4x speed per turn of exploration. I find this makes for a better dungeon crawl, as time becomes a precious resource.

Comment: @harlandski Is it specified as 30 minutes in-game time or real time?

Comment: That's a good question. I assumed in-game time, but maybe it means real time.